# line-bot post message not received by AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, direct-line-botframework

I am new to Line-bot, and i have successfully connected my `AWS lambda API gateway` to my line developers platform webhook.

I know the link is successful because every time i click on `verify` in line developers platform, a log is printed in `AWS cloudwatch`. IE: the verify button in `line developers` post a hello world message to the API gateway, and my lambda function prints back the log details, along with a `"statusCode": 200`

**Lambda function**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
if 'body' in event:
    message_event = json.loads(event['body'])['events']
    print(message_event)
```

My question is, I have added my line-bot to my line chat via the QR code provided by the line developers platform as suggested in the line guide.. However, each time i post a text from the line chat, it does not seem to be captured / invoked by lambda.. Because no logs get captured in `AWS cloudwatch`

Any help will be appreciated!

Note: [line bot guide](https://developers.line.biz/en/docs/messaging-api/building-bot/)